# Angular - detect click background div but not on divs within

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

On [ollynural.github.io](http://ollynural.github.io), in the portfolio page i'm  trying to simulate a pop-up div giving more information on the project you clicked on. To go back off the pop-up, I've added an ng-click so when you click on the main portfolio-pop-up container, the pop-up is removed.

Is it possible to only have the parts of the portfolio-pop-up div that are exposed (not on the photo nor the description white box) removing the main div once clicked? So you can click freely on the picture and the white box

```
<div class="portfolio-pop-up container" ng-click="losePortfolioFocus()">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <img class="portfolio-image portfolio-image-popup" src="{{portfolioImageClass}}">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 pop-up-container">
                    <div class="pop-up-row">
                        <div class="col-xs-9" style="background: red">
                            <h1>
                                {{portfolioTitle}}
                            </h1>
                            <p>
                                {{portfolioDescription}}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3" style="background: cyan">
                             <a href="{{portfolioLink}}">Click me</a>
                             <div ng-repeat="tech in portfolioTech">
                                {{tech}}
                             </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS

```
$scope.losePortfolioFocus= function() {
    angular.element('.portfolio-pop-up').css("display", "none");
}
```

CSS

```
.portfolio-pop-up {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* color with alpha transparency */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.70);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, can post more css or code if needed

Comment: Pass `$event` into your click event and check `target` matches or don't put your popup container in the same container as the background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can stop the propagation of the `click` event on the element that wraps the pop-up's content like this:

```
<div class="portfolio-pop-up container" ng-click="losePortfolioFocus()">
  <div class="row" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
  ...
  </div> 
</div>
```

This way the clicks inside the popup will not trigger the `losePortfolioFocus()` handler.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! Although I think I should probably look into the event chain and work out what it's doing for myself. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you crawl up the event chain from you event' target and check whether your `pop-up-container` is in there. This way, you'll have a way to distinguish click in the pop-up or out of it.